# Using Swinject to inject a Model class instance into a View class instance in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection, swinject

In a Swift 2.0, Single Page Application project, in XCode 7.0.1, with the Swift dependency injection framework [**Swinject**](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject), I am doing the following:

DuplicateProtocol.swift:

```
protocol DuplicateProtocol { var id: String { get } }
```

SingletonProtocol.swift:

```
protocol SingletonProtocol { var id: String { get } }
```

DuplicateProxy.swift

```
class DuplicateProxy: DuplicateProtocol {
    let id: String

    init ( id: String ) {
        self.id = "DuplicateProxy." + id
    }
}
```

SingletonProxy.swift:

```
class SingletonProxy: SingletonProtocol {
    let id: String

    init ( id: String ) {
        self.id = "SingletonProxy." + id
    }
}
```

ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    var duplicate: DuplicateProtocol?
    var singleton: SingletonProtocol?

    required init? ( coder aDecoder: NSCoder ) {
        print( "ViewController.init?", duplicate, singleton )
        super.init( coder: aDecoder )
    }

    override func viewDidLoad () {
        print( "ViewController.viewDidLoad", duplicate, singleton )
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

AppDelegate.swift:

```
import Swinject
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate
{
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application ( application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]? ) -> Bool {

        let container = Container()
        let singleton = SingletonProxy( id: "first" )

        container.register( SingletonProtocol.self ) { _ in singleton }
        container.register( DuplicateProtocol.self ) { _ in DuplicateProxy( id: "second" ) }

        container.registerForStoryboard( ViewController.self ) {
            r, c in c.duplicate = r.resolve( DuplicateProtocol.self )
        }

        print( "AppDelegate.application" )

        return true
    }
}
```

And this is the console log I am unfortunately getting:

```
ViewController.init? nil nil
AppDelegate.application
ViewController.viewDidLoad nil nil
```

Put as simply as I can: what changes do I need to make? Thank you, JBM.

Comment: I wanted to add the tag **swinject** but it seems that my rep isn't high enough yet.

Comment: I also don't have a privilege to add a tag. It is helpful if someone add **swinject** tag.

Comment: Claudio, thank you for adding the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initializer injection is not available if you want to instantiate the view controller from a storyboard because UIKit framework calls `init?(coder:)`.

Instead, property injection should be used to instantiate it from a storyboard:

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {
    var duplicate: DuplicateProtocol?
    var singleton: SingletonProtocol?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Still the implicit instantiation of UIWindow and the initial view controller is not supported by Swinject. You need to instantiate them explicitly as the following example does.

```
import Swinject
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    var container: Container {
        let container = Container()
        let singleton = SingletonProxy( id: "first" )

        container.register( SingletonProtocol.self ) { _ in singleton }
        container.register( DuplicateProtocol.self ) { _ in DuplicateProxy( id: "second" ) }

        container.registerForStoryboard( ViewController.self ) {
            r, c in c.duplicate = r.resolve( DuplicateProtocol.self )
        }

        return container
    }

    func application ( application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]? ) -> Bool {
        let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        self.window = window

        let storyboard = SwinjectStoryboard.create(name: "Main", bundle: nil, container: container)
        window.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()

        return true
    }
}
```

By the way, you don't have to handle the singleton instance by yourself. Swinject has Singleton (aka Container) Object Scope, which can be set with `.inObjectScope(.Container)` [as documented here](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject/blob/master/Documentation/ObjectScopes.md).

**UPDATE 2**

Swinject version 0.3 supports the implicit instantiation of UIWindow and its root view controller from "Main" storyboard. [Here is its documentation](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject/blob/master/Documentation/Storyboard.md).

Comment: Hi Yoichi. I edited my original question to both include the suggestion you made, and post the entire code from a simple test project, as I tried to implement your suggestion without success. I am sure I am doing something wrong that would be obvious to you, but not to me, so that is why I have posted my entire, stripped-down code.

Comment: You've lost me a little Yoichi because you said "Initializer injection is not available if you want to instantiate the view controller from a storyboard" but then immediatly said "property injection should be used to instantiate it from a storyboard." So should it be instantiated from a storyboard or not? Do you mean it should be: var newViewController = app.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier( "ViewController" )  -->  app.window.rootViewController = newViewController  -->  app.window.makeKeyAndVisible() ?

Comment: Instantiation from a storyboard (**SwinjectStoryboard**) is available. The difference of **initializer injection** and **property injection** is [documented here](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject/blob/master/Documentation/InjectionPatterns.md). Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice Yoichi, THANK YOU. And thank you for being kind about my stupid questions.